# What is the difference between the size required to store a variable and "memory required to store a variable"?

Tags: memory, operating-system

Will it be different for different OS platforms. Say memory in bytes occupied by a variable will be different in Windows/Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Informally when someone asks any of the following?

```
What is the size required to store a variable?
```

OR

```
What is the memory required to store a variable?
```

The actual question that is being asked is:

```
What is the size of the memory required to define the variable?
```

A **variable** is nothing but memory, and **variable identifier** is used to identify, what specific bytes are we talking about?

Yes size of variable in `bytes` is different for different OS/architectures. This is the reason we have `cross-platform` data types.

For example: In `C` we have integer data types like `int16_t`, `int32_t` which will always occupy `16 bits` and `32 bits` of memory respectively as opposed to `int` which can occupy different number of `bytes` on different machines.